# spring boot upgrade from 2.1.2 to 2.6.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i have recently upgraded spring boot version from 2.1.2 to 2.6.6 .it ran and worked while test in my local. but when i deploy into server with same code and app.yaml file it didn't run.

Below is the log from server,

```
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.055 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811   :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.6)

Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.055 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811  (empty)
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.053 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811   \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.053 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.053 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811   =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.052 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811  (empty)
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.052 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811    .   ____          _            __ _ _
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.052 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811   /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
Apr 19, 2023 @ 17:43:02.052 172.20.132.62:9080/ifrs-common:811  ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
```

Comment: There is far too little information here to help, also your outut is totally unreadable and doesn't show an error or anything.

Comment: Try to clean .m2 folder, and retry